# File.createNewFile() gives java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Tags: java, linux, file

My OS is fedora and I use the following code to create a file:

```
String destFile = "/var/www/html/nykkos/app/webroot/AssimilatorGenerator/Script_May6/db/"+"musics.db";
File destinationFile= new File(destFile);
if(!destinationFile.exists()) {
destinationFile.createNewFile();
}
```

It gives me the following exception at the line `destinationFile.createNewFile()`

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

Why this exception occurs and how can I overcome the same?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo chmod a+rwx /var/www/html/nykkos/app/webroot/AssimilatorGenerator/Script_May6/db` changes the rights for **all** to the directory. Better look first whether `chown`, changing the owner/group might do. Or a combination of same group and giving the group all rights.

BTW createNewFile is seldom needed.

Comment: When I run this java code, it works perfect from eclipse. But I get this exception when I run this from Apache. Has it something to do with the permission?

Comment: `ls -al` lists all files with `owner:group` and rwx-rights for owner, group and others. You need at least rw-rights in the directory, for "Apache" / the running java process. **Maybe someone reading this might give a more definite answer.**

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because the user you are running the JVM with has not the right permission to write at that path. But please post more deatils for a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check `owner` mode and `permission` setting of parents directories setting. If there is no `write` permission in Your OS, you will get the exception.